# How do you refresh the remotes in Magit?

Tags: emacs, github, magit

Magit is really nice, but I have yet to figure out how to create a remote branch from it, or how to refresh the remote branches it knows without deleting the remote and adding it back in.
Currently I go to github, add a branch, then go into magit, delete the remote, and then add it back. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refreshing a remote branch should be done with a [git fetch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

With [Magit (documentation)](http://magit.github.io/master/magit.html#Pushing-and-Pulling-1):

> Typing <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> will run `git fetch`.
>   It will prompt for the name of the remote to update if there is no default one.
>
> Typing <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> will always prompt for the remote.
>
> Typing <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> will run [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).
>   When you don’t have a default branch configured to be pulled into the current one, you will be asked for it.

As [Rémi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14090/r%C3%A9mi) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216353/how-do-you-refresh-the-remotes-in-magit/24216586?noredirect=1#comment37394752_24216586),  <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> would fetch all remotes.

Actually, as [akaihola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15770/akaihola) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216353/how-do-you-refresh-the-remotes-in-magit/24216586#comment92492318_24216586) in 2018:

> If you type <kbd>F</kbd>, you get the "pull" menu.
>   Then:
>
> - <kbd>p</kbd> pulls from the **push default** (see <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>), and
> - <kbd>e</kbd> from elsewhere (e.g. another remote branch).

---

Creating a remote branch should be pushing a local branch to a remote:

> Magit will run `git push` when you type <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>.
>   If you give a prefix argument to <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>, you will be prompted for the repository to push to.
>    When no default remote repository has been configured yet for the current branch, you will be prompted as well.
>
> Typing <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> will only push the current branch to the remote.
>   In other words, it will run `git push <remote> <branch>`.
>
> **The branch will be created in the remote if it doesn’t exist already**.
>   The local branch will be configured so that it pulls from the new remote branch.
>
> If you give a double prefix argument to <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>, you will be prompted in addition for the target branch to push to.
>   In other words, it will run `git push <remote> <branch>:<target>`.

Comment: you also have "f a" to fetch all remote

Comment: @Rémi true, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Awesome. Fetch `a` is partly what I was looking for, It causes new remotes to show up in the remote manager. I never noticed that a push caused the remote branch to be created if it didn't exist or that `-u` would get me a prompt. I suspect I'm missing something about the prefixes to push. I see `-force` `-upstream` and `-dry run`. So I think I might be confused about prefix arguments.

Comment: `F` `F` isn't available any more in the current versions.

Comment: @akaihola what shortcut would be used for `git fetch` then (in the current versions)?

Comment: @VonC `F` `F` used to do a `git pull`. A `git fetch` is still done using the `f` submenu.

Comment: @akaihola OK: what shortcut would be used for `git pull` now?

Comment: @VonC, if you type `F`, you get the "pull" menu. Then `p` pulls from the push default (see `b` `M-p`), and `e` from elsewhere (e.g. another remote branch).

Comment: @akaihola Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.